# POWERSHELL on scheduled task : windows server 2019 and excel 2013

Tags: excel, powershell

Had an issue with excel 2013 invoked with scheduled task via powershell.
I added "Desktop" directory on C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile. (for 32 bits too)

Now i can read excel file but i can't save excel file.
Windows server 2019.
Excel 2013.

It was working on 2008 R2.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Check owner and permission on file, for user that must save it.

Comment: Checked. it's a domain admin that run the script. Creation of new excel file failed too

Comment: Then check permission to this directory, some system directories not able for domain admins without rewrite permisions

Comment: Admin has the right permission. same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a trick.

Microsoft said that automation on server side is not supported by devs.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Solution is here :
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/66afe200-0bff-41f5-a2ca-e43007ad8f31/excelapplication-powershell-script-error-running-from-scheduled-task?forum=exceldev

Open **comexp.msc**.
Navigate to DCOM config and find Microsoft Excel Application. Right clic and properties
[image]

Identity tab >> This user and choose a user who has a profile on this computer.

[image]

You do not need Desktop folders on systemprofile dirs.